# How do I get french text FEMMES.COM to index as language variants of FEMMES

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I need FEMMES.COM to get tokenized as singular + plural forms of the base word FEMME.

### Custom Analyzer Config

"analyzers": [        {            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",            "name": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer",            "tokenizer": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",            "tokenFilters": [                "lowercase",                "asciifolding"            ],            "charFilters": [                "html_strip"            ]        }    ],    "tokenizers": [        {            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",            "name": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer_ms_tokenizer",            "maxTokenLength": 300,            "isSearchTokenizer": false,            "language": "english"        }    ],    "tokenFilters": [],    "charFilters": []}

### Analyze API call for FEMMES

{    "analyzer": "text_language_search_custom_analyzer",    "text": "FEMMES"   }

### Analyze API response for FEMMES

{    "@odata.context": "https://one-adscope-search-eu-stage.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.AnalyzeResult",    "tokens": [        {            "token": "femme",            "startOffset": 0,            "endOffset": 6,            "position": 0        },        {            "token": "femmes",            "startOffset": 0,            "endOffset": 6,            "position": 0        }    ]    }

### Analyze API response for FEMMES.COM

{    "@odata.context": "https://one-adscope-search-eu-stage.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.AnalyzeResult",    "tokens": [        {            "token": "femmes",            "startOffset": 0,            "endOffset": 6,            "position": 0        },        {            "token": "com",            "startOffset": 7,            "endOffset": 10,            "position": 1        }    ]    }

### Analyze API response for FEMMES COM

{    "@odata.context": "https://one-adscope-search-eu-stage.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.AnalyzeResult",    "tokens": [        {            "token": "femme",            "startOffset": 0,            "endOffset": 6,            "position": 0        },        {            "token": "femmes",            "startOffset": 0,            "endOffset": 6,            "position": 0        },        {            "token": "com",            "startOffset": 7,            "endOffset": 10,            "position": 1        }    ]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was not correct. Azure Search implementation actually applies the language tokenizer BEFORE token filters. This essentially made the WordDelimiterToken filter useless in my use case.

What I ended up having to do was to pre-process data BEFORE I uploaded to Azure for indexing. In my C# code, I added some regex logic that would break apart text like FEMMES2017 into FEMMES 2017, before I sent it to Azure. This way, when the text got to Azure, the indexer would see FEMMES by itself and properly tokenize as FEMME and FEMMES using the language tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this one out myself after some experimentation. I found the MappingCharFilter could be used to replace . with , before the indexer did the tokenization. This allowed the lemmatization/stemming to work as expected on the terms in question. I need to do more thorough integration tests with our other use cases, but I think this would solve the problem for anybody facing the same type of issue.

Comment: FYI, I had another edge case where this data...

http://www.sarenza.com/selection-chaussures-grandes-occasions-femmes?abv=1

would not properly tokenize femmes into femme and femmes.

I ultimately solved this by including several more characters in my CharMappingFilter, and replacing all of them with comma.

#$€£%&+/=<>@_µ§¤°!?"'`~^.:;()[]{}*-

The only I could not replace was backslash \. The Azure Search Service would fail creating the index when I included that backslash in a char mapping so I left that one out. This solves this edge case for me.